# MySQL, PHP - how to make the page faster?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that consists of a big table that takes its data from different tables and then calculates different parameters for each row.

The table itself is a dataTable so its has different JQUERY and JS

The page is VERY slow. First i have like a minute of data uploading (i see 5 rows then 10, then 20...) and then i have like 30 seconds of css uploading (the table looks different).

Is there ways to make it faster?

The whole code:

```
<?php
require 'init.php';
//protection
logged_out_protect_Vendor();

$data = ShowMyProjects($con);
$flag_DueDate = HaveDueDate($data); //flag is 0 if there are no projects with duedates
$guideAgent="http://dub-entas-   124.corp.ebay.com:83/tool/tagmania/guidelines/TagmaniaForAgents.docx";
$user_name=$_SESSION['username'];?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/shCore.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/demo.css">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/demo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 9, "desc" ]]
} );
} );
</script>

<title>Agent View</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" >
</head>


<body class="dt-example">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="menu">
            <img src="images/Tazlogo.gif" id="taz">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            <li> <a href="finishedWorking.php" title="By clicking on this link, you will unlock all the rows that are locked by you and can`t be answered by anyone (including you). The lock state happens when you enter the tagging page and then close it without answering the question">Unlock my rows</a></li>
            <?php echo '<li><a href ="' .  $guideAgent . '"> TagMania Guide </a></li>'; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="page">
        <div class="welcome"> 
        <?php
        echo 'Good Day ' . $_SESSION['username'] . ', here are your tasks: ';
        ?>
        </div>
        <br>

<div class="container">
        <form method="get">
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
            <thead>
            <tr>

            <th> Project name </th>
            <th title="general guidelines to this task"> Guidelines</th>
            <th>  Task type</th>
            <th title="Task can be new, in-process and finished. It also can have a status `archiveDM` meaning that the DM decided to archive it.">  Status</th>
            <?php
                //check that we have a duedate column
                if ($flag_DueDate==1)
                    echo '<th title="Some tasks have duedate and some don`t. Those who have a due date will be colored yellow, two days before the duedate and red after the due date. If you finish them, they will return to the regular white background"> Due Date </th>';
            ?>
            <th title="Finish date for all the tasks that were finished">  Finish Date</th>
            <th  title="The number of the rows in the task that have been tagged by you">  Tagged by you</th>
            <th  title="The number of rows that you locked. If you see here something other than 0, please click on `Unlock my rows`">  Locked by you</th>
            <th  title="The number of rows that had been tagged by all the agents">  Tagged sample</th>
            <th  title="The total number of rows in this task">   Total sample</th>
            <th  title="Link to the tagging page">  </th>
            <th  title="Here you can see a report summarizing your answers on this task"> Results</th>
            <th  title="Here you can download the task in Excel format. You can download the task on every stage - new, in process or finished">  Download </th>
            <th  title="Click on the checkboxes tasks that you don`t want to appear on the view. Then click on the archive button. Notice that they will dissapear for all the agents.">  Archive</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
            <tr>

            <th> Project name </th>
            <th title="general guidelines to this task"> Guidelines</th>
            <th>  Task type</th>
            <th title="Task can be new, in-process and finished. It also can have a status `archiveDM` meaning that the DM decided to archive it.">  Status</th>
            <?php
                //check that we have a duedate column
                if ($flag_DueDate==1)
                    echo '<th title="Some tasks have duedate and some don`t. Those who have a due date will be colored yellow, two days before the duedate and red after the due date. If you finish them, they will return to the regular white background"> Due Date </th>';
            ?>
            <th title="Finish date for all the tasks that were finished">  Finish Date</th>
            <th  title="The number of the rows in the task that have been tagged by you">  Tagged by you</th>
            <th  title="The number of rows that you locked. If you see here something other than 0, please click on `Unlock my rows`">  Locked by you</th>
            <th  title="The number of rows that had been tagged by all the agents">  Tagged sample</th>
            <th  title="The total number of rows in this task">   Total sample</th>
            <th  title="Link to the tagging page">  </th>
            <th  title="Here you can see a report summarizing your answers on this task"> Results</th>
            <th  title="Here you can download the task in Excel format. You can download the task on every stage - new, in process or finished">  Download </th>
            <th  title="Click on the checkboxes tasks that you don`t want to appear on the view. Then click on the archive button. Notice that they will dissapear for all the agents.">  Archive</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>

            <tbody>
            <?php
            //i already used the data object so we need to point the pointer at the beginning of the data again
            mysqli_data_seek($data, 0);

            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                $taskId = $row['ProjectID'];
                $tasktype = $row['ProjectType'];

                include 'WhatTaskIsIt.php';

                $totalSampleQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*)as C FROM $table WHERE TaskID= $taskId";
                $totalSample = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $totalSampleQuery));

                $taggedSampleQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*)as C FROM $table WHERE TaskID= $taskId AND rowstatus=2";
                $taggedSample = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $taggedSampleQuery));

                $lockedByVendorQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*)as C FROM $table WHERE TaskID= $taskId AND rowstatus=1 AND Agent = '" . $user_name . "'";
                $lockedByVendor = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $lockedByVendorQuery));

                // Update Project status to "In-Process" if they are New but have tagged sample
                if ($taggedSample['C']>0){
                    $ProjectStatusQuery = "SELECT ProjectStatus FROM projects WHERE ProjectID=$taskId";
                    $ProjectStatus = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $ProjectStatusQuery));

                    if ($ProjectStatus['ProjectStatus'] == 1) //if the project is NEW (but have tagged rows)
                    {
                        $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE projects SET ProjectStatus=2 WHERE ProjectID=$taskId";
                        mysqli_query($con,$UpdateQuery);
                    }
                }

                //lets check what happened to the project status
                $ProjectStatusFinalQuery = "SELECT StatusName FROM projects LEFT JOIN projectstatuses ON projects.`ProjectStatus`=projectstatuses.`StatusID` WHERE ProjectID=$taskId";
                $ProjectStatusFinal = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $ProjectStatusFinalQuery));

                $VendorTaggedQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(*)as C FROM ' . $table .' WHERE taskID = ' . $taskId . ' AND Agent = "' . $user_name . '" AND RowStatus=2';
                $VendorTagged = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $VendorTaggedQuery));

                $linkToDownload = 'downloadFile.php';

                if ($flag_DueDate==0) {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>' . $row['ProjectName'] . '</td>
                        <td> <a href ="' .  $row['GuidelinesURL'] . '"> Guidelines </a> </td>
                        <td>' . $row['TypeName'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $ProjectStatusFinal['StatusName'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . showDate($row['FinishDate']) . '</td>
                        <td>' . $VendorTagged['C'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $lockedByVendor['C'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $taggedSample['C'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $totalSample['C'] . ' </td>
                        <td> <a href= ' . $link . '?id=' .  $row['ProjectID'] . '&start_task=1&prevID=0>Start Working</a></td>
                        <td><a href= taskResults.php?id=' .  $row['ProjectID'] . '>Results</a> </td>
                        <td> <a href= ' . $linkToDownload . '?id=' .  $row['ProjectID'] . '>Download</a></td> 
                        <td class ="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="archive" name="archive" value=" ' . $row['ProjectID'] . '"> </td> </tr>';
                }   

                if ($flag_DueDate==1){

                if ($row['due_date'] == NULL)
                    $duedate = "";
                else
                    $duedate = $row['due_date'];

                //lets check if this duedate is late or not (but only for unfinished projects)
                if ($row['FinishDate'] ==NULL)
                    $color = Color_DueDate($duedate);
                else
                    $color ="noBackground";

                echo '<tr  class=" . ' .$color . '">
                        <td>' . $row['ProjectName'] . '</td>
                        <td> <a href ="' .  $row['GuidelinesURL'] . '"> Guidelines </a> </td>
                        <td>' . $row['TypeName'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $ProjectStatusFinal['StatusName'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . showDate($duedate) . '</td>
                        <td>' . showDate($row['FinishDate']) . '</td>
                        <td>' . $VendorTagged['C'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $lockedByVendor['C'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $taggedSample['C'] . '</td>
                        <td>' . $totalSample['C'] . ' </td>
                        <td> <a href= ' . $link . '?id=' .  $row['ProjectID'] . '&start_task=1&prevID=0>Start Working</a></td>
                        <td><a href= taskResults.php?id=' .  $row['ProjectID'] . '>Results</a> </td>
                        <td> <a href= ' . $linkToDownload . '?id=' .  $row['ProjectID'] . '>Download </a></td> 
                        <td class ="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="archive" name="archive" value=" ' . $row['ProjectID'] . '"> </td> </tr>';
                }   
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="archive" value="Archive" name="submit" />
        </form>
    <br><br>

    <!--imlementing archive button-->
<script>
var $varsToSend="";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#archive").click(function(){
    $varsToSend="";
        $(".archive:checked").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);    
        $varsToSend=$varsToSend+$this.val()+";";
        });
        //console.log($varsToSend);

            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'archiveTasksVendor.php',
                data: {
                    projectID : $varsToSend
                },
                success : function(data){
                location.reload();
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }

        });
    });
});
</script>


    <?php include 'footer.html'; ?>     
</div>
```

For those who wanted to see the tables:
The tables in the query are: Projects, ProjectTypes, ProjectPriorities , ProjectStatuses, 
UserGroups

```
TABLE `projects` (
  `ProjectID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DM_GROUP_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `DM_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Vendor_GroupID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Site` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectType` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Project_Comment` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreationDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdateDate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `due_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinishDate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectStatus` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `fileName` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ProjectID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1368 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `projecttypes` (
  `TypeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TypeName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `GuidelinesURL` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectQuestion` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ValidReasons` VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ValidAnswers` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `style` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Aspectlist` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TypeID`)
 ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `projectpriorities` (
  `PriorityID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PriorityName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PriorityID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `projectstatuses` (
  `StatusID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StatusName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StatusID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `usergroups` (
  `GroupID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GroupName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `GroupType` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `RelatedTo` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GroupID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code?

Comment: Ok, i will add the whole code in a second

Comment: Can you show us the database create statement (index, column types and so on)?

Comment: Yes or you can use `explain`, to show how your query works and wich index it will use or where youu need an index

Comment: I edited: have the whole code and the tables

Comment: try `CREATE INDEX vendorgroupid_projectstatus_idx ON projects (Vendor_GroupID, ProjectStatus);`

Comment: It didnt help. Still very slow. I guess the problem is not in DB but in the rest of the code? :(

Comment: Have yu tried to execute the statement on mysql console? if yes how many seconds thay need? So you cansay if it is the statemant!

Comment: In the console it takes 5 seconds :(

Comment: for db improvement, try using indexes as mentioned in another comment. Also, try to separate your php from your html - i see you execute queries after server has start sending data to browser. Try to get all the data you will need before any html output

Comment: Andrew - is it an advice for the code to be more clear or you think it can help with the speed? I tried using the index - it didnt help

Answer (score 3):

### Too many queries

You are running queries `totalSampleQuery`, `taggedSampleQuery`, `lockedByVendorQuery`, `ProjectStatusFinalQuery` and `VendorTaggedQuery` (as well as potentially `ProjectStatusQuery` and `UpdateQuery`) for *each* row. If you are selecting all 253 rows from the main query, that gives you 253 + 253 + 253 + 253 + 253 (+253 +253, possibly) extra queries. All those queries add up *quickly*.

Flip your approach around: create *one* query that produces the same information as `totalSampleQuery` for *all* the rows in the main table, run that query *once* outside the loop, and use its results. Repeat the process for all other `SELECT` queries you are currently running in the loop. Even better, instead of running those extra queries separately, `JOIN` them with the main query.

For example, instead of running

```
SELECT COUNT(*)as C FROM $table WHERE TaskID= ?
```

two hundred times, run

```
SELECT TaskID, COUNT(*) as C FROM $table
GROUP BY TaskID
```

. You will get the counts for all tasks in one query. Pull all the returned rows into an array, using `TaskID` as the key, and use the data from that array inside the main loop.

Note: you will probably want to add some kind of filter to the new query to pull only the data related to the projects you are displaying. But your schema does not actually contain a column named `TaskID`, so it's difficult to suggest the right condition.

### Ordering and pagination

After optimizing the queries, you are still left with a table that displays 250 rows of data. It takes a lot of HTML to display that table, the browser takes a while to render and style it, and after all that jQuery DataTables has to attach itself to the table and sort the rows in your preferred order.

1. Consider limiting the page to 20-50 rows and adding pagination, that will cut down on the volume of data you're processing and the amount of HTML you're sending.
2. Instead of using DataTables to order the data after the page loads, sort the records on the server - by using `ORDER BY` in the main query, if at all possible.

---

There are more issues with your code that are not related to this particular problem.

1. The changes you're doing in "*Update Project status to "In-Process" if they are New but have tagged sample*" should be done when the "tagged sample" action is performed, not here. What if you need to display the project status elsewhere, are you going to copy-paste this "Update project status" snippet over?
2. Like andrew noted in the comments, you should restructure your code so that data collection is not interlaced with the HTML generation. Read up on "MVC" and "separation of concerns".
3. One of your queries mentions `TaskID` in `$table`, another mentions `taskID` in the same `$table`. Those two refer to the same column if your MySQL is running on Windows, but on Linux the table and column names are case-sensitive, which means one of those queries will produce an error. Same goes for `rowstatus` and `RowStatus` further down.
4. Where is your error handling? If there's an error in one of the queries, you will continue rendering the page as if nothing had happened.
5. You are not escaping any HTML when you display the data from the DB - what if there's a project named `Sample Pro</tr></table></div>ject</div></body>`?

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I will try to do it. The problem is that the code was a patch on a patch, written by different people. Thats why it is so hard to understand exactly what to change... I am re-writing the whole program now... This is only one file of 60... :)

Comment: The problem with your suggestion and why it was not implemented like that is because each project has a different type. Each type has a different table from which all the calculations are being done. Thats why i have 'SELECT COUNT(*)as C FROM $table WHERE TaskID= ?". The $table is different each line...

Comment: Well, that's not obvious from the code you posted :) How many types are there? If it's four or five types, you're still much better off running four or five queries rather than 250. If it's closer to 20-50 types, you might want to look at denormalizing this part and having an actual table/materialized view for that kind of information (and taking a hard look at your DB structure).

Comment: The amount of types is unknown. Today it is 9 and tomorow, new projects will be presented. so its hard to say. The implementation and the DB were done in this way so it will be generic. Each project is different, so it has a different data table and we have one table with the general information like project name-type-date created and so on. Do you think creating a View will help with the speed? How i can do it?

Comment: @Alex: *Anything* that switches you from "one query for each row" to "one query for all rows" will help with the speed. With serious data sets, you'll definitely want to get a denormalized view or dedicated columns for those counters, but if your data is only several hundred rows, you should be fine with an ordinary view. (I'm also wondering how your type tables are split between "generic" and "specific" - if you are able to use the same column names, `TaskID`, `rowstatus` and  `Agent`, regardless of the type, they should probably be present in the generic table).

Comment: @Alex: you should also update the question with all this extra information you've posted here in the comments - as it stands now, there's a lot of relevant details missing from the main question, making it harder for others to contribute their answers.

Comment: DCoder: I have one generic table "projects" that has the general data and i have a special table for each type. But each special table has 6 columns that are the same for all tasks (like taskId, taskType stuff like that). That is how i am using it. They must be in the generic table and in the specific table so the task will be identified. rowStatus is not a generic row. Its something very specific per row - this data doesnt exist in the projects table because it is a task property (project is general and each project can have a lot of tasks)

Comment: @Alex: if `rowStatus` is so specific to each task type, you should *not* be able to query it with the same condition for all tasks. Maybe you need an extra column in the generic table that represents the data you are currently querying through `rowStatus` in a more generic format?

Comment: I dont think you understand. We have for example 4 projects: A, B, C and D. Each project, every week has a new task. So project A can have now 10 tasks, B has 2 tasks and C and D have no tasks. A task is a row with a lot of information. RowStatus means: was it answered, is it in a process of answering or is it new. So each table has a column named RowStatus. The table projects has an information about a task, not about it Rows. It has an information like when the task was created, what type of project is it, when was it last updated, who is the group who work on it. Stuff like that.